# C - Build options for SDLGFX

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm not sure if the correct term is "build options". Here's the code that doesn't work :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>

polygonRGBA(renderer, x, y, 6, 255, 0, 0, 155); // this part
```

I've used this to compile it :

```
gcc -o test main.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs̀
```

polygonRGBA() is a function from SDLGFX. It seems I've not added the correct options to build it (except this part, SDL2's compilation works). The given error is :

```
undefined reference to 'polygonRGBA'
```

What is the correct option to add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can use `pkg-config --list-all` and grep for the name of the package you want to add compile or link flags for. But I was a little surprised to see that there is no `pkg-config` option for SDLGFX even though I have the `-dev` package installed on my (Ubuntu) system. Nor does `sdl-config` include the libraries for it (not that it necessarily should).

So try adding `-lSDL2_gfx` to your invocation,

```
gcc -o test main.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_gfx
```

When `pkg-config` fails, you can make a good guess by searching for the library by name,

```
$ find /usr/lib | grep gfx
....
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_gfx.so
...
```

and using `-l` with the part between `lib` and `.so`: lib**SDL2_gfx**.so

Comment: Oh thanks. It works. If I understand your last part, there is two ways to find the link flags needed, first is using pkg-config ; the second is using find | grep. For example, if a lib is called libMATH.so, the flag needed is -lMATH ?

Comment: Exactly. And maybe also `-L/path/leading/up/to/lib`, but most libraries end up in the system/platform library folder like above. SDL includes its own little config script, but it also includes a pkg-config file, so this should work equivalently: `pkg-config sdl2 --cflags --libs`.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again.